# Can I get a visa for another country while away from my home town?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, international-travel, singapore, australian-residents

Hi I am holding Indian Passport but I am living in Australia on a student visa. I am planning to take a trip to Singapore next year and wanted to know if I can apply for a Singapore visa from Australia.
I do have a valid US (B1/B2) visa on my passport and I need a visa for Singapore. I am confused if I can apply for a visa from Australia or will I have to travel to India and apply for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, to apply for a visa for country C from within country B while being a national of country A, all one has to show to C’s embassy in B is proof of lawfully being in B.

Thus, as you are legally (temporarily) residing in Australia on an Australian student visa, you can apply for whichever visas you need from within Australia at the embassies these countries have in Australia.

Cases in point: as a German citizen residing in Japan, I successfully applied for a Chinese visa from within Japan. Likewise, when I was temporarily residing in Finland (though not registered as a temporary resident because I was below the 90 days limit), I applied for my visa to Russia in Finland.

Comment: Requirements actually vary by country. Some countries only allow you to request a visa from the consulate that covers your actual place of residence (long term), others will allow you to request it anywhere. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/148244/when-applying-for-a-visa-has-there-ever-been-a-case-of-embassy-asking-for-proof/148256#148256 for examples.

Comment: @jcaron Ah yes, I had a similar case when applying for my Japanese work visa where I had to go to the Hamburg consulate in whose jurisdiction I lived.

Answer (score 4):

You are a resident of Australia and you are entitled to apply for Singapore Visa from Australia itself.

Also, since you have Visa for Australia / USA, you don't need Visa for 96 hours of stay if you are transiting to another country.

https://www.ica.gov.sg/enteranddeparting/before/enteranddeparting_before_vftf

Comment: I am an Indian resident with an Australian student visa. Also I do need to stay for more than 96 hrs as I am visiting Singapore for work

Comment: You are living in Australia means that you are an Australian Resident, but an Indian Citizen.

You can definitely apply for visa to virtually any country in Australia.

Comment: Oh got it. Can you share any link where I can check out the process for Singapore? I checked their website but they have offline process via an agent in India.

Comment: Singapore embassy doesn't have direct application. You have to apply via a local travel agent. It can be 30 SGD and upwards. If you know a Singapore PR/Citizen, they can apply on your behalf and it will only take one day.

Comment: This is the information I could find - https://www.mfa.gov.sg/Services/Visitors/Visa-Information