# Consulate asking for PR

Tags: visa-refusals

do embassies, generally speaking, ask a person applying for a visa their PR of the country in which they're currently applying for a visa (i.e the country where the embassy is based) or an eventual other visa for the country in which they're currently, in order to verify their legal presence there?

Example: My name is A, I'm an Egyptian citizen living in France. Once I go to a US istitution there in order to apply for a visa (I assume my passport is totally empty) and once I showed that I have enough funds to sustain and provide for myself there, would they ask a french PR in order for myself to be eventually issued a visa or do they simply bother about their related country entry conditions?

EDIT: The question does not pertain this current coronavirus hysteria and if the question's too broad or general, restrict your answer to the US or UK embassies cases.

Comment: What do you mean by "PR"?

Comment: Permanent Residence

Comment: Not possible to answer in general since it varies by country. Are you asking specifically about the USA?

Comment: The question's general, but for the sake of example, I might assume that I am.

Comment: Currently, US nonimmigrant visa applications are only being received online; US consulates and US embassies abroad have suspended visa services. Source: _https://www.usa.gov/visas_.

Comment: I'm not including this coronavirus hysteria, my question pertains to normal periods and normal circumstances.

Comment: You might add that information into your question (using the "edit" button below its text) so subsequent readers can understand your query without having to read through the comments to harvest relevant information.

Comment: You might also review this one: _https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/149864/can-i-get-a-visa-for-another-country-while-away-from-my-home-town?noredirect=1&lq=1_

Comment: I don't know whether the US checks the lawfulness of visa applicants' presence in the country where they are applying.  They certainly didn't check *mine* when I applied to have pages added to a US passport many years ago.  The UK certainly does, and Schengen consulates generally require applicants to apply where they reside, which is a stricter requirement than simply being lawfully present.

Comment: @phoog I don't think comparing your experience with the OPs is appropriate as it is A) An entirely different situation and more importantly B) You are a US citizen (since you have a US passp), they must serve you no matter your status as that is YOUR embassy/consulate. This person is not a national of the US, and in general (from my experiences with various consulates) they do require you possess some form of legal status in the country from which you apply. Your references to UK and Schengen are more appropriate.

Comment: But why do they ask of a legal proof of residence in the country of presence, if it's logically an unrelated matter to them?

Comment: @user Several justifications are possible. The country to which application is made might wish to spread the workload among its embassies and consulates, rather than permitting applicants to choose the facility which the applicants think will be most receptive. Further, embassies and consulates in the applicant's country of residence are more likely familiar with procedures and documents and language in the country of residence, and thus more facile in their evaluation of applications filed from that country that necessarily contain documents in that country's language.

Comment: @Ozzy sure, it's not the same situation at all, but I can tell you that when I apply for consular services at the Dutch consulate in the US (I am a dual citizen) they *do* ask for proof that I reside in their district and evidence of lawful presence. So the fact that the US consulate in Amsterdam didn't ask me for evidence of lawful presence, coupled with the fact that I've never seen anything saying that lawful presence is necessary to apply for a US visa, leads me to suspect that it is not in fact necessary. I don't know for certain, though.

Comment: @user I have no idea.  In reaction to Ozzy's comment, I double-checked the requirements for applying for a Dutch passport at a Dutch diplomatic mission, and they do indeed require proof of lawful residence.  The same is required for visas, of course.  The UK allows applications outside the country of residence only for certain visa types; see https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/country-selection (expand "can I enter any country?").

Comment: Thanks to everybody for all details you've provided.